# SQL replace NULL with string with #replace command

Tags: sql, string, replace

the following pl sql code is not working, dont know why..

```
Replace(Replace(Replace(Users,   '0','NO'),
                                 '1','YES'),
                                  null,'Not defined')
```

If the cell is empty then I nedd 'Not defined' string.

I would appreciate you if you answer my question!

Comment: What are you trying to do? Just create a query or updating data? Could you please provide some sample data and expected outcome?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace operates on strings; null is not a string. `coalesce` is the best way to fill in a value for a potentially-null field:

```sql
select
  coalesce(
    replace(
      replace(Users, '0','NO'),
      '1',
      'YES'
    ),
    'Not defined'
  )
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
SELECT
(

     CASE
        WHEN users = 0 THEN 'NO'
        WHEN users = 1 THEN 'YES'
        ELSE 'Not defined'
    END AS Results
)
FROM your_table
```

If you don't want to use CASE, maybe try this :

```
UPDATE your_table SET users = 'YES' WHERE users = '1'
UPDATE your_table SET users = 'NO' WHERE users = '0'
UPDATE your_table SET users = 'Not defined' WHERE users IS NULL
```

With the function REPLACE :

```
UPDATE your_table
SET column_name = REPLACE(column_name, 'old text', 'new text')
```

I hope it will help you :)

Comment: Hello Onyx, thanks for the answer, it is possible to resolve without case when? Just with replace function? I dont want to use case when for some other reasons. Thanks! :)

Comment: I edited my code. I hope it is what you looking for :)